# Hand cursor not showing up for an NSButton added in a Model sheet

Tags: macos, cocoa, mouseover, mouse-cursor, nsbutton

I have subclassed NSButton and created a class of my own, in which I have added the code to show up hand cursor when mouse pointer comes over the button. It's working for buttons that were added in normal views. But when I used the same class for a button inside a model sheet, cursor is not showing up. What might be the reason? Any idea!

This is the code I have added in NSButton subclass

```
- (void)resetCursorRects {
/*
 * change cursor type to a poiting finger when it gets into HyperLink frame.
 */
[super resetCursorRects];
[self addCursorRect:[self bounds] cursor:[NSCursor pointingHandCursor]];
```

}

Answer (score 2):

In Interface Builder, make sure your sheet's Window/Panel has `Title Bar` checked.

Since it's a sheet the title bar won't actually be visible, but for some reason cursor tracking seems to be disabled when this property is off.

Answer (score -1):

Instand of Subclassing create a `Category` of NSButton. and override the
`resetCursorRects` method (same as the above).

`#import` the new Category to your controller and try.

if you not familiar with `Category` try [this](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/objective-c-categories/) out.